# How to implement Solidity modifier functions in Rust?

Tags: rust, solidity, solana

Solidity modifiers are syntactic sugar to add code around functions. Modifiers are reusable across in multiple functions, reducing repetitive checks.

```
modifier lock() {
    require(slot0.unlocked, 'LOK');
    slot0.unlocked = false;
    _; // run function here
    slot0.unlocked = true;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
function my_function() external override lock returns (uint256 some_val) {}
```

How to implement a similar pattern in rust? Currently I'm adding the required code directly inside my functions. But this causes a lot of repetition.

```rs
fn my_function() -> u8 {
    // modifier pre code
 
    // My function code here ....

    // modifier post code
}
```

Comment: To roll your own syntatic sugar via Rust, you'd use macros. Because Rust macros operate on the syntax tree and not on the token level, they're quite a bit less hacky than C macros.

Comment: `#[access_control]` if you're using Anchor, should do the trick?

Comment: Anchor's `#[access_control]` only performs a-priori validation. Modifier should let you insert code at end of the function.